# how to get cakephp recursive data

Tags: cakephp, tree, recursive-query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
  `employees_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employees_firstname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employees_middlename` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employees_lastname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_gender` enum('M','F') NOT NULL,
  `employees_dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `employees_emailaddress` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employees_password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employees_datejoined` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `employees_code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employees_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `employees_mobile` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employees_designation` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employees_bussiness_account` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employees_image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employees_supervisers_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employees_work_location_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employees_date_added` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employees_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `employees_code_UNIQUE` (`employees_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `employees`
--

INSERT INTO `employees` (`employees_id`, `employees_firstname`, `employees_middlename`, `employees_lastname`, `employee_gender`, `employees_dob`, `employees_emailaddress`, `employees_password`, `employees_datejoined`, `employees_code`, `employees_status`, `employees_mobile`, `employees_designation`, `employees_bussiness_account`, `employees_image`, `employees_supervisers_id`, `employees_work_location_id`, `employees_date_added`) VALUES
(16, 'Aneesh', 'C', 'S', 'M', '2012-11-05', 'aneesh.cs@calpinetech.com', '7106499a88fd79197ddbff61829993c9', '2010-12-07', 'cas927', 1, '9876543210', 1, 1, 'Betson.JPG', 0, 1, '2012-11-27 00:00:00'),
(17, 'Betson', 'T', 'Thomas', 'M', '2012-11-05', 'betson@calpinetech.com', '7106499a88fd79197ddbff61829993c9', '2008-12-06', 'cas450', 1, '9876543210', 6, 1, NULL, 16, 1, '2012-11-27 00:00:00'),
(18, 'test', 'test', 'test', 'M', '2012-11-12', 'test@calpinetech.com', '7106499a88fd79197ddbff61829993c9', '2012-11-06', 'cas999', 1, '9876543210', 1, 1, NULL, 16, 1, '2012-11-27 00:00:00'),
(19, 'asdsa', 'asdsad', 'asdsad', 'M', '2012-12-03', 'test@calpinetech.com', 'd8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4', '2012-12-24', 'ca0999', 1, '9876543210', 1, 1, NULL, 17, 1, '2012-12-04 00:00:00');
```

This is my table. Here `employees_supervisers_id` is the `employees_id`. How can we get the recursive data through cakephp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are trying to create parent/child relationships between records in the same table. If that is what you are asking, you can create those relationships in the Employee model like this:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Supervisor' => array(
        'className' => 'Employee',
        'foreignKey' => 'employee_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
);

public $hasMany = array(
    'Underlings' => array(
        'className' => 'Employee',
        'foreignKey' => 'employees_supervisers_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP gets it by default if you create the relationships between models.

If you do:

```
$employees = $this->Employee->find('all');
```

And you have created the relationships between models, you would be able to access the recursive data with something like this:

```
$employees['Employee']['Supervisor']['employees_firstname'];
```

I would recommend you to take a look at the documentation referring to the linking between models:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: I need a tree level data from only one table.

Answer (score 0):

To build a tree you need to use the [TreeBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html), and have `parent_id` and/or `lft`, `rght` field in your model.

`lft` and `rght` are for [MPTT](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) data

In your case you can configure the behavior to use your `employees_supervisers_id` field